# How can I stop Apache Storm Nimbus, UI and Supervisor?

Tags: apache-storm, upstart, nimbus

I run Apache Storm in a cluster and I was looking for ways to stop and/or restart Nimbus, Supervisor and UI. Would writting a servise help? What should I write in this service file and where should I place it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, writing a service is the recommended way to run Storm. The commands you want to run are `storm nimbus` to start Nimbus (minimum 1 per cluster), `storm supervisor` to run the supervisor (1 per worker machine), `storm ui` (1 per cluster) and `storm logviewer` (1 per worker machine). There are other commands you can also run, but you can find these by simply running `storm`, it will print a list.

Regarding how to write the service, take a look at the upstart cookbook http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/.

There's an example script here you can probably use to get started https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84289

Comment: Thank you very much! Your feedback is very helpful and I will try to follow the instructions (useful for a newbie like me) but I already run these services. My problem is that I don't know how to stop them.

Comment: You don't need to run a special command to stop a running Storm command. Since the commands (e.g. `storm nimbus`) run in the foreground, you should be able to just ctrl-c out of them. For upstart, if you start your Nimbus service with `initctl start storm-nimbus`, you should be able to stop it with `initctl stop storm-nimbus` (not that familiar with upstart tbh, but that's what Google tells me).

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can make them as service and start them up as the node starts and same can be used to stop them.

/etc/rc.d/SERVICE start or stop or restart

Answer (score 0):

We can easily stop them using the command "ps -aux | grep nimbus" or supervisor etc. Then we have to find the process id and kill it with the “kill” command.